From pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame call to foreach to lambda is able to print but is not able to append to list

Below PySpark code is able to print the values

But, the obj.append does not seem to have any affect.

Environment


24/09/17 14:46:12 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.5.2                                                                                                
24/09/17 14:46:12 INFO SparkContext: OS info Linux, 6.8.0-40-generic, amd64                                                                                     
24/09/17 14:46:12 INFO SparkContext: Java version 11.0.11 

from pyspark.sql.types import Row
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder\
                .master("local[*]")\
                .appName("ETL")\
                .config("spark.executor.logs.rolling.time.interval", "daily")\
                .getOrCreate()

sample_streamed_data = spark.createDataFrame([
    {"value": Row(apple='12', banana='14', carrot='0')},
    {"value": Row(apple='10', banana='10', carrot='2')}
])

print(f"{sample_streamed_data} --> {type(sample_streamed_data)}")

obj = list()
sample_streamed_data.foreach(lambda l :      print(l.asDict().get('value')))
sample_streamed_data.foreach(lambda l : obj.append(l.asDict().get('value')))
print(obj)
sample_streamed_data.foreach(lambda l :      print(l.asDict().get('value')))


Output is

DataFrame[value: struct<apple:string,banana:string,carrot:string>] --> <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
Row(apple='12', banana='14', carrot='0')
Row(apple='10', banana='10', carrot='2')
[]
Row(apple='10', banana='10', carrot='2')
Row(apple='12', banana='14', carrot='0')


I was expecting to see a list of pyspark.sql.types.Row objects, but it turns out to be a blank list.

